Angular 17 Functional Resolver Unable to Inject Services Into Jest Test Case
Overview
Hi there,
I am in the process of migrating my Angular app from v14 to v17, and one of the tasks that comes with this is replacing the old deprecated Resolver classes with the new ResolverFn implementation.
The issue that I am having is that I had previously injected services that I am unable to now inject without getting the inject() must be called from an injection context error whenever I run test code. (Documentation for the error found here).
My Old Resolver
@Injectable()
export class TimespanResolver {
  private memberGranularity$: Observable<GranularityType>;

  constructor(
    private timespanService: TimespanService,
    private coreCache: CoreCacheService
  ) {
    this.memberGranularity$ = this.coreCache
      .MemberSettings()
      .pipe(
        map((settings) =>
          settings == null
            ? GranularityType.Weekly
            : settings.DefaultGranularity
        )
      );
  }

  /**
   * Updates the timespan when the route changes
   * @param route -- route snapshot
   */
  resolve({ data }: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<Timespan> {
    const granularity$ = data.initGranularity
      ? of(data.initGranularity)
      : this.memberGranularity$;

    return firstValueFrom(
      granularity$.pipe(
        map((granularity) =>
          TimespanService.GetTimespanFromGranularity(granularity)
        ),
        tap((timespan) =>
          this.timespanService.UpdateTimespan(
            timespan,
            data.timespanDisplayText
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

My New Resolver
export const timespanResolver: ResolveFn<any> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  __: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  const coreCache = inject(CoreCacheService);  // Causes an injection error
  const timespanService = inject(TimespanService); // Causes an injection error

  let memberGranularity$: Observable<GranularityType>;

  memberGranularity$ = coreCache
      .MemberSettings()
      .pipe(
        map((settings) =>
          settings == null
            ? GranularityType.Weekly
            : settings.DefaultGranularity
        )
      );

    const granularity$ = route.data.initGranularity
    ? of(route.data.initGranularity)
    : memberGranularity$;

    return firstValueFrom(
      granularity$.pipe(
        map((granularity) =>
          TimespanService.GetTimespanFromGranularity(granularity)
        ),
        tap((timespan) =>
          timespanService.UpdateTimespan(
            timespan,
            route.data.timespanDisplayText
          )
        )
      )
    );
};

My Current Test
it('should update with default granularity from user settings if one isnt specified', fakeAsync(() => {
        // arrange
        jest.spyOn(service, 'UpdateTimespan');
        const newMoment = Date.UTC(2019, 1, 0);
        const realDateNow = Date.now.bind(global.Date);
        const dateNowStub = jest.fn(() => newMoment.valueOf());
        global.Date.now = dateNowStub;
        TimespanService._masterMomentRef = moment();
        jest.spyOn(TimespanService, 'GetTimespanFromGranularity');
        let snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = {
            data: {}
        } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

        let stateSnap: RouterStateSnapshot = {
        } as RouterStateSnapshot;

        // act
        timespanResolver(snapshot, stateSnap);
        flush();

        let res: Timespan;
        service.Timespan$.subscribe(t => res = t);
        flush();

        let startDate = res.StartDate.year() !== res.EndDate.year() ?
                        res.StartDate.format('MMMM Do, YYYY')
                        : res.StartDate.format('MMMM Do');
        let endDate = res.EndDate.month() !== res.StartDate.month() ?
                        res.EndDate.format('MMMM Do, YYYY')
                        : res.EndDate.format('Do, YYYY');

        // assert
        expect(service.UpdateTimespan).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(TimespanService.GetTimespanFromGranularity).toHaveBeenCalledWith(GranularityType.Weekly);
        expect(res.Granularity).toBe(Weekly);
        expect(res.DisplayDate).toMatch(`${ startDate } - ${ endDate }`);
        global.Date.now = realDateNow;
        TimespanService._masterMomentRef = moment();
    }));

What I have Tried

I tried injecting in the input of the lambda expression (Resulted in same error):

export const timespanResolver: ResolveFn<any> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  __: RouterStateSnapshot,
  coreCache = inject(CoreCacheService),
  timespanService = inject(TimespanService)
) => {
// Code removed for brevity
}


I tried adding a class to hold the injected classes (constructors are considered within the injection context) (Resulted in same error);

export const timespanResolver: ResolveFn<any> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  __: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  let services = new ResolverServices();
  let coreCache = services.coreCache;
  let timespanService = services.timespanService;
  // Remaining code removed for brevity
};

class ResolverServices() {
  public coreCache = inject(CoreCacheService);
  public timespanService = inject(TimespanService);

  constructor() {
  }
}


I looked around for the best way to get an Injector from the resolver so that I could call runInInjection but was unable to find any examples.


please share how you are using the resolver in the routing, also the entire resolver code including imports

It was failing in my Jest code and because of this I had thought that I set it up incorrectly. Turns out that this was setup correctly, the issue was my Jest test.
All I had to do was wrap timespanResolver(snapshot, stateSnap); in my test with TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => {});

you never mentioned it was a test case :( in the question!

Yeah, I had assumed when I shouldn't have. Should I edit or delete the question?

Edit it with test case and answer it yourself and give green tick!

done! thanks for your quick response today!

The issue was not related to the Resolver, that was functioning fine when I would run my app.
The issue was that when the resolver was called from the Jest test, it would then be outside of the injection context and would have this error.
To solve this, I simply wrapped the resolver function call in TestBed.runInInjectionContext:
it('should update with default granularity from user settings if one isnt specified', fakeAsync(() => {
        // Other code removed for brevity
        let snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = {
            data: {}
        } as ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

        let stateSnap: RouterStateSnapshot = {
        } as RouterStateSnapshot;

        // act
        TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => {
            timespanResolver(snapshot, stateSnap);
        });
        flush();
        // Other code removed for brevity
    }));

